# Firebase iOS Authentication - Performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm currently adding Firebase Authentication to my iOS application. I can sign up and sign in users, however, I'm struggling to find where I can add a segue to move on to the next screen.

```
func signInUser(email: String, password: String){
    // creates user with the firebase autenthication platform
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    }
    
    // would the segue go here?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute your code inside the `signIn` function completion handler:

```
func signInUser(email: String, password: String){
    //creates user with the firebase autenthication platform
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        if let error = error as? NSError {
            // Handle sign in error
            switch AuthErrorCode(error.code) {
                ...
            }
        } else {
            // No errors: Perform segue here...
        }
    }
}
```